# Understanding HJB equation for the infinite horizon consumption control problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, optimal-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation

**Context**
Given the following maximization problem as well as wealth dynamics
$$\max\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\gamma} e^{-\beta t} c_t^\gamma \mathrm{d} t\right]$$
$$\mathrm{d} X_t=X_t\left(r+\pi_t(\alpha-r)\right) \mathrm{d} t-c_t \mathrm{~d} t+\pi_t X_t \sigma \mathrm{d} W_t, \quad X_0=x>0$$
we need to prove that Hamilton–Jacobi–Bellman (HJB) equation is given by

$$\sup _{c \geq 0, \pi}\left\{\frac{1}{\gamma} c^\gamma-\beta V(x)+x(r+\pi(\alpha-r)) V^{\prime}(x)-c V^{\prime}(x)+\frac{1}{2} \pi^2 x^2 \sigma^2 V^{\prime \prime}(x)\right\}=0$$
where $0<\gamma<1, \beta>0, c_t \geq 0, X_t \geq >0, t\geq 0$

**My problem**
I know that the HJB equation in the general form is given as
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(t, x)+\sup _{u \in U}\left(F(t, x, u)+\mathcal{A}^u V(t, x)\right)=0 \\ V(T,x) = \Phi(x)$$
which is roughly
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(t, x)+\sup _{u \in U}\left(F(t, x, u)+(\text{(values in front of dt )}) V(t, x)' + \frac 12 (\text{(values in front of dWt )}^2) V(t, x)''\right)=0$$

In our case $\Phi = 0$ as there is an infinite horizon and $F(t, x, u) = \frac{1}{\gamma} e^{-\beta t} c_t^\gamma $.

Even though I agree with the term $$x(r+\pi(\alpha-r)) V^{\prime}(x)-c V^{\prime}(x)+\frac{1}{2} \pi^2 x^2 \sigma^2 V^{\prime \prime}(x)$$
in the equation we need to proof, **the equation does not match completely** :

- No $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(t, x)$ term in front
- In $\sup(\cdot)$, $F(t, x, u)$ does not contain the exponent (though I think it might be due to plugging in $e^{-\infty} = 1$)
- Not clear why $-\beta V(x)$ appears

Comment: Hi: I can't help you ( my only exposure to this field is some self study here and there ) but maybe this youtube video helps a little. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=us8JoyjD0Oo

Comment: What is $c_t$ ?

Comment: Well, it's a variation of the optimal consumption problem, so $c_t$ refers to the amount of consumption at time $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a discounted optimal control problem. Define for simplicity

$$dX_t=f(X_t,c_t,\pi_t)dt+g(X_t,\pi_t)dW_t$$

where our control inputs are both $c_t$ and $\pi_t$. The HJB equation is given by

$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(t, x)+\sup _{c\ge0,\pi}\left\{\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(t, x)f(x,c,\pi)+\dfrac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}(t, x)g(X_t,\pi)^2+\frac{1}{\gamma} e^{-\beta t} c^\gamma\right\}=0.
$$

Now, if we let $V(t,x)=e^{-\beta t}W(x)$, the above expression becomes

$$
e^{-\beta t}\left(-\beta W(x)+\sup _{c\ge0,\pi}\left\{W'(x)f(x,c,\pi)+\dfrac{1}{2}W''(x)g(X_t,\pi)^2+\frac{1}{\gamma} c^\gamma\right\}\right)=0
$$
and the exponential term can be dropped as it is always nonzero to get the desired result

$$
\sup _{c\ge0,\pi}\left\{-\beta W(x)+W'(x)f(x,c,\pi)+\dfrac{1}{2}W''(x)g(X_t,\pi)^2+\frac{1}{\gamma} c^\gamma\right\}=0.
$$

So, to summarize:

- The term $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}(t, x)$ becomes $-\beta W(x)$.
- The exponential term is factored out.

Comment: But the resulting expression is in terms of $W'$ and $W''$, while we need to show that in terms of $V$. We can get back to $V$ but it returns me to the place where I was. Plus, without the assumption$V(t,x)=e^{-\beta t}W(x)$, the term $+\frac{1}{\gamma} c^\gamma$ does not appear

Comment: @student I am sorry but I do not understand your point. It is the standard way for dealing with that problem. You can easily get $V$ from $W$. Note also that $V(0,x_0)=W(0,x_0)$. $V$ has to have this structure for the HJB equation to be satisfied.